# Equal an int value from firebase realtime database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-database

I have an int `userCoin` that holds the user coin and I want to equal Firebase' value to my int value.

I have this code

```
    self.databaseRef = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
NSString *userID = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid;
[[[_databaseRef child:@"users"] child:userID] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    // Get user value
    NSLog(@"%@",snapshot.value[@"Profile Picture"]);
    userCOin = snapshot.value[@"Coin".init];


} withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

but it wont work. It says:

> ViewController.m:45:18: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'id _Nullable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is giving you an `NSNumber*` and that isn't the same thing as an `int`. Call `snapshot.value[@"Coin"].intValue` to convert it to an `int`.